# Why this recursive javascript function returns undefined?

Tags: javascript, function, recursion, undefined

In the following recursive function, I expect the function to return `"arrived"` at the end but instead, it returns `undefined`. Isn't that when the excution goes in the `if` block the code should return? Appreciate your comments on this.

```
function myFun(i){
    if(i===0){return ('arrived');}
    i = i - 1;
    myFun(i);
}
```

If I change the code as follows then it'll return `"arrived"` but still don't know why the above doesn't return `"arrived"`.

```
function myFun(i){
    if(i===0){return ('arrived');}
    i = i - 1;
    return myFun(i);
}
```

Comment: @anthony, i is sent in the parameter

Comment: If you have a function `foo`, which does nothing but call a function `bar`, which returns a value `"BAR"`, would you expect `foo` to return the result of the call to `bar` if `foo` didn't have a `return` statement? `function foo() { bar() } function bar() { return "bar" } foo();` A recursive function is no different.

Comment: Your example totally makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first function does not return a value because **all code paths** must return a value. And after the first line, there is no `return` statement. It only returns a value when called with `0` as parameter.

Comment: If you call the function `myFun(5)` then it ultimately reaches to `myFun(0)` and at that point it should return `"arrived"`, right? So, I mean if I call `myFun(5)`, how is it different from `myFun(0)` in which I directly call the function with argument `0`?

Comment: In that case you have 6 nested (recursive) calls. The **6th call** is done with i === 0, and yes it returns a string ***to the context of the fifth call***. That value is then 'thrown away' because from where the 5th (and 4th and 3rd etc) calls happen, which is line 3, there is no `return` statement.

Comment: Now I see, great explanation, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is a functional heritage and so writing your program in a functional style will yield the best results.

This means avoiding things like

- imperative style statements `for`, `if`, `switch`, etc that do not return a value
- mutation or variable reassignments like `i = i + 1`

```js
const myFun = i =>
  i === 0
    ? "arrived"
    : myFun (i - 1)
    
console.log (myFun (10))
// "arrived"
```

Notice expressions, unlike statements, evaluate to a value. We made the following changes

- `function` statement `function myFun (i) { ... }` replaced with a function *expression* `myFun (i) => ...`
- `if` statement replaced with ternary *expression*, eg `condition ? ifTrue : ifFalse`
- variable assignment statement `i = i - 1; myFun(i)` replaced with *expression* `myFun(i - 1)`

Note, the `return` statement itself is a side effect and has little use in a functional JavaScript program.

Going along with the other answer here, *all code paths must return a value*! An advantage to writing your program in a functional style means you can't write a function that doesn't return a value, nor can you write a conditional with only one branch.

TL;DR: use functional style and your problem automatically vanishes